# How to fix 'Unexpected directive imported by the module. Please add a @NgModule annotation.'

Tags: firebase-authentication, ionic4

I am trying to add disable Control in forms so I can disable the field. I created a new directive for disable Control. When I tried to run the registration. i received an error.

In register.module.ts, I already added Disable Control Directive in import array but still received an error when trying to go to register page which is Unexpected directive...Please add a @ Ng Module annotation.

register.page.html:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Status</ion-label>
  <ion-select form Control Name="status" placeholder="Select One" [disable Control]="disable">
    <ion-select-option value="ACTIVATE">ACTIVATE</ion-select-option>
    <!-- <ion-select-option value="VENDOR">VENDOR</ion-select-option> -->
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

register.module.ts:

```
import { DisableControlDirective } from '../directives/disable-control.directive';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
...
DisableControlDirective
...
],
declarations: [RegisterPage]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your directive in the `declarations` not `imports`:

register.module.ts:

```
import { DisableControlDirective } from '../directives/disable-control.directive';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
 ...
],
declarations: [RegisterPage, DisableControlDirective]
})
```

Based on [this tutorial's](https://netbasal.com/make-your-angular-forms-error-messages-magically-appear-1e32350b7fa5) code sample:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/netanel-control-er?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: great, don't forget to upvote and mark as answer :)